# same code python opencv run in 2 computers and 2 results are different?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vuong2.mp4')
Frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print (Frames)
# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i use this code to get total frame of video.
my computer run 553frames
my friend's computer run 132 frame and 132 is correct.
we use same python.same opencv version.
what is wrong :(.
sorry for my bad English